# No aparecen los JLabel al usar el metodo paint

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo una etiqueta(JLabel) en la cual pongo una imagen, para eso sobrescribo el metodo paint que tiene la misma y usando la clase abstracta Graphics pinto la imagen en la eitqueta con el metodo g.drawImage(), el problema es que dentro de esta, hay otra etiqueta más, la cual no aparece, comprobe viendo las coordenadas que no es posible que la imagen este encima de la etiqueta que no aparece, dado que la imagen no ocupa el espacio donde tendria que estar la etiqueta. Creo que estoy usando mal el metodo paint, hay algo que se me esta olvidando, cabe aclarar que pinto la imagen en vez de usar el metodo setIcon() de la clase JLabel, porque me conviene hacerlo asi producto de otras cosas que no son trascendentales para solucionar el problema.

```
private final JLabel CERRAR = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(Punto.class.getResource("/x.png").getPath()));
private BufferedImage ima;

public Punto(final int x, final int y, final ImageIcon img) {

    this.eliminado = false;

    setLayout(null);
    setBounds(x, y, 50, 40);

    InitComponentes(img);
    InitEventos();

    repaint();

}

private void setToolTipText(final ImageIcon img) {
    if (img.equals(CLICKIZQ)) {
        setToolTipText("Click Izquierdo");
    } else if (img.equals(CLICKDRC)) {
        setToolTipText("Click Derecho");
    }
}

private void InitComponentes(final ImageIcon img) {

    setCerrar();
    setToolTipText(img);
    try {
        ima = ImageIO.read(new File(img.getDescription().substring(1)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

}

private void InitEventos() {

    PuntoEventos pe = new PuntoEventos(this);

}

private void setCerrar() {
    CERRAR.setVisible(true);
    CERRAR.setBounds(40, 0, 10, 10);
    add(CERRAR);
}

public void setEliminado(final boolean deleted) {
    this.eliminado = deleted;
}

public boolean isEliminado() {
    return eliminado;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String coordenadas = "x: " + this.getX() + ", y: " + this.getY();
    String tipoClick = this.getToolTipText();

    return coordenadas + " - " + tipoClick + " - " + eliminado;
}

public JLabel getCerrar() {
    return CERRAR;
}

@Override
public void paint(final Graphics grphcs) {

    grphcs.drawImage(ima, 0, 0, 32, 32, null);

    grphcs.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
    grphcs.setFont(new Font("Dialog", 1, 15));
    grphcs.drawString("1", 11, 21);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible que la imagen no se vea porque el método `paint()` este pinta los gráficos sobre todo lo que contenga el componente dentro, en otras palabras si tu imagen de "background" es lo suficientemente grande para ocultar la imagen del componente `JLabel` este no se podrá ver.

Usar en cambio el método `paintComponent` este método pinta en el diseño que tendrá el componente, sin interrumpir a los demás.

Cree dos componentes `Atomo` y `Atomo2` (extienden de JLabel), les aplique una imagen de background con los diferentes métodos, uno con `paint()` y el otro con `paintComponent()`, a estos también les agregue un JLabel que tiene una imagen de un circulo de color negro.

El el primer caso el JLabel con el circulo negro, quedaba por debajo del background del Atomo, en el segundo caso el JLabel se visualizaba por arriba.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahí se puede ver como el método `paint()` pinta por encima de lo que contenga dentro, mientras que `paintComponent()` pinta el fondo y deja a los componentes de arriba verse

(Como si fuera un JPanel que al agregar componentes estos siguen viéndose arriba.)

Código del Atomo2:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Atomo2 extends JLabel {

    private BufferedImage image;
    private JLabel CIRCULO;

    public Atomo2(int x, int y, String path) {
        setSize(100, 100);
        setLocation(x, y);      
    
        setLayout(null);
    
        createBufferedImage(path);
    
        add(createCirculo());
    }

    private void createBufferedImage(String path) {
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private JLabel createCirculo() {
        CIRCULO = new JLabel();
        CIRCULO.setSize(60, 60);
        CIRCULO.setLocation(25, 4);
    
        CIRCULO.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("circulo.png")));
    
        return CIRCULO;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, 70, 70, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
    
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.setFont(new Font("Dialog", 1, 15));
        g.drawString("1", 34, 40);
    }

}
```

El numero 1 corresponde al `Atomo2`, no al JLabel del circulo negro, pero para demostrar que aun el método `paint()` pinta todo por arriba, lo deje.

Este es solo un ejemplo, hay modificaciones a conveniencia, sigue en si la misma estructura que tu clase, el Buffered, el JLabel, etc, quite métodos que daban error al no tener la clase completa.

Comment: Hola si gracias por el aporte, efectivamente era eso